# How To Create Multiple-Choice Chatbot with Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, chatbot

i want to create chatbot that can generate pre defined multiple choice answers like this picture below like yes/no answers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o28s.png)

but after some research in the internet, i could not find the solution that meets my needs. i want to use python to create this chatbot and only simple rule based chatbots.

Many thanks!

Comment: A "chatbot" suggests a chatting platform. Many chatting platforms have a python API; ie, a python module/library specifically to create chatbots. Are you interested in a particular chatting platform? irc? email? discord? signal? telegram? etc etc. Choose your favourite, then search whether it has a python API.

Comment: Or you could just write a "chatbot" for the command-line interface. This requires no external module.

Comment: Also note this extremely similar question: [Is there a faster and more simple way for randomizing the order of these questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68741012/3080723)

Answer (score 0):

What platform do you wish to make the Chatbot on

Many popular platforms have their own chat api (discord , instagram , reddit)

Or do you want to have it in your own website ?

Discord - You can use the package discord.py
Sample bot (Source - discord.py docs)

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')

client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

Instagram - You can use instapy (https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy). I personally have no experience with making instagram bots or stuff

Reddit - You can use PRAW. Its a package for reddit automation and stuff (https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).I have never made a reddit bot either

If you want it in your own website (like the screenshot shows) , there are many tools that can do this WITHOUT you needing to code. If you want to make your own you can either

- Write a big if else statement
- Use Chatterbot (https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

All applications (like your chatbot) are made of two different parts, **frontend** and **backend**. Frontend is responsible for graphical displaying of text, image,buttons,etc to users, which these data are given from backend. 
The backend is where the logical processes are done. 
For your purpose, for backend, you can use django and write your python codes there. Then for showing text and those pre defined choices, you should know about html, css and javascript. 
You can simply send your multiple choice answers from backend to frontend, then frontend interprets them and shows them like the picture you sent above.