# SyntaxError: unicodeescape

Tags: python, python-unicode

I am trying to build a bot which gives a random answer from CSV file.
Piece of code I have problem with:

```py
def get_data(lounaslista):
    with open('C:\Users\p7l1n\Desktop\lounasbotti\lounaslista.csv', 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        data = [row for row in r]
    return data
```

Error I'm getting:

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

I tried solutions from following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733658/is-there-a-faster-and-more-simple-way-for-randomizing-the-order-of-these-questio?noredirect=1&lq=1/).

Comment: Your imput csv isn't in (correct) unicode.  Either it's in another encoding, or you need to fix the mojibake.  In either case this has nothing to do with python.

Comment: The linked post is orthogonal to the issue here (csv encoding).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! What encoding is your text file? Can you try reading it with a different encoding?

Comment: Encoding does not matter here, error is in the path string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Use double slash instead of simple slash in path.

```py
def get_data(lounaslista):
    with open('C:\\Users\\p7l1n\\Desktop\\lounasbotti\\lounaslista.csv', 'r') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        data = [row for row in r]
    return data
```

Example with simple variable:

```
a = 'C:\Users\p7l1n\Desktop\lounasbotti\lounaslista.csv'
# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

# With double slash:
a = 'C:\\Users\\p7l1n\\Desktop\\lounasbotti\\lounaslista.csv'
print(a)  # C:\Users\p7l1n\Desktop\lounasbotti\lounaslista.csv

# Or use raw string:
a = r'C:\Users\p7l1n\Desktop\lounasbotti\lounaslista.csv'
print(a)  # C:\Users\p7l1n\Desktop\lounasbotti\lounaslista.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

The backslash character in strings is used as an escape character. For example `\n` is a newline, `\"` and `\'` can be used to insert `"` and `'` into string literals without terminating those literals. You can also write `\U00000000` to insert a character with that code point (instead of `00000000` you can have any hexadecimal number).

To insert a literal backslash, you have to escape the backslash, like so: `\\`

For Windows file paths, this gets a bit tedious, so there is an alternative: raw string literals, like so: `r'C:\Users\p7l1n\Desktop\lounasbotti\lounaslista.csv'`. This disables escape sequences.

A third option is to use forward slashes instead: `'C:/Users/p7l1n/Desktop/lounasbotti/lounaslista.csv'`. Windows generally accepts forward slashes as an alternative path separator.